# Cannot migrate AspNetUser entity in Entity Framework Code First Approach in .NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project using Visual Studio 2013. I am using Entity Framework Code First Approach to interact with database. But I am having a problem with migrating data because of built-in identity system in ASP.NET. Everything was fine before I touch to identity system.

These are the steps I have done.

1. I registered an account from UI using built-in identity system. So AspNetUsers table is created in database.
2. I created AspNetUser class to my code because I need to work with it.
3. Then I run migration and update database command. It throws error.

This is my AspNetUser class

```
public class AspNetUser
    {
        [Required]
        public String Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String UserName { get; set; }
        public String PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public String SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Discriminator { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my db context class

```
public class AyarDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AyarDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ItemContactInfo> ItemContacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Mail> Mails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
```

This is the error I got.

> There is already an object named 'AspNetUsers' in the database.

How can I migrate AspNetUser class? I registered using UI because I auto create the other tables need for identity system. How can I migrate that class and map with AspNetUsers table that is already existing in database.

Answer (score 0):

As the error explains, that table already exists and is accessible in this way:

```
var user = context.Users.First(u => u.Id == myId);
```

If you want to extend the user class and add properties, you can inherit it:

```
public class MyAppUser : IdentityUser
{
    // don't include properties already in IdentityUser
    public string MyNewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/

Comment: Maybe, I can access user in code. What if I have to update my model again in my future? that error will come again to me.

Comment: Yes, you can access the user table in code as shown above or with a user manager. Depends on what you are trying to do. If you just want to add additional properties inherit and add properties. If you want to redo password hashing or internals that is a major effort (IMO)

Comment: No I cannot add new entity using migration in this situation cause that AspNetUser is included in the migration class file.

Comment: You don't need the AspNetUser class. Remove it and the DbSet. That table is handled by the Identity base class. Clarify your needs.